# Python - Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From python, I want to send a notification to all my android users who subscribed to a specific topic.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
firebase_admin.messaging.ApiCallError: Firebase Cloud Messaging API has not been used in project 432453324 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.goo
gle.com/apis/api/fcm.googleapis.com/overview?project=432453324 then retry.
```

I enabled the fcm for my android app, and it works fine when I send a notification from the console to android, but with python there's something wrong, what is it?

Here's my code:

```
topic = 'new'

# See documentation on defining a message payload.
message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        'title': 'hahaha',
        'body': 'test',
    },
    topic=topic,
)

# Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
response = messaging.send(message)
# Response is a message ID string.
print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```

Comment: Are you using the server key for the same project which you used for sending it from console ? I would suggest just double check it once

Comment: I will check now

Comment: But if it's any confirmation, in this python script it successfully writes data to firestore

Comment: That response with the message id is a confirmation

Comment: Your code here seems ok, the problem might be on your `FirebaseMessagingService`. It might be though that FCM platform is broken, I have an app that is supposed to receive 5 different notifications on any given day and I'm only receiving 2 (if any). The Messaging service is not as good as the rest of Firebase :-(

Comment: You can also try to resubscribe the user, that fixed my missing notifications.

Comment: Thanks Racu! That's unfortunate :( . What I did is I renamed my topic and now it works fine, I don't know what it changed